# MTG Mirage Mirror copying Medomai the Ageless

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-commander

Hey guys just a quick question. Last night I played an EDH game and I have a [Medomai the Ageless](https://scryfall.com/card/ths/196/medomai-the-ageless) onto the battlefield. It's my opponent's turn and he uses [Mirage Mirror](https://scryfall.com/card/hou/165/mirage-mirror) to copy Medomai.

He used [Chainer, Dementia Master](https://scryfall.com/card/tor/56/chainer-dementia-master) as the commander. So on his turn he copies Medomai with Mirror, use Chainer to bring back [Gary](https://scryfall.com/card/thb/99/gray-merchant-of-asphodel) and deals X damage to me and another opponent, he attacks my opponent with Mirage which is a copy of Medomai, the person doesn't have flying blockers so damage gets through triggering Medomai ability to get an extra turn. Then after finishing his turn he sacrifice Gary with a sacrifice outlet and Mirage Mirror becomes the artifact again. Now he starts the extra turn doing the same thing (copying Medomai, bringing back Gary with Chainer, attacking the opponent with Mirage, damage gets through and gets an extra turn, sacrificing Gary, Mirage becomes the artifact again) and the loop goes and goes.

In this scenario Mirage Mirror copying Medomai over and over and getting combat damage through does not get affected by Medomai's second ability (**Medomai the Ageless can’t attack during extra turns.**)?

Comment: Somewhat surprised no one has pointed out that Medomai is a legenedary creature, so it (or the mirror) goes to the graveyard upon copying.  Not a big deal if you have enough mana and Chainer on the battle field.

Comment: @John, that's because Mirage Mirror is copying an *opponent's* Medomai, so the Legendary rule isn't relevant.

Comment: @John with M14 the Legend rule changed from one in the game to one per player - clone effects no longer kill opponent legendaries.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

"[Cardname] can’t attack during extra turns" places an attacking restriction on the card.

> 508.1c The active player checks each creature he or she controls to see whether it’s affected by any restrictions (effects that say a
>   creature can’t attack, or that it can’t attack unless some condition
>   is met). If any restrictions are being disobeyed, the declaration of
>   attackers is illegal.

Therefore, any creature with that restriction can not be declared as an attacker during extra turns. It does not matter how the extra turn was created.

Note that Medomai has two separate abilities. They happen to work together by design (or rather against each other), but they are not connected ruleswise.

Now the restriction only applies while declaring attackers. If Mirage Mirror was somehow attacking before it turned into Medomai (e.g. [March of the Machines](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMarch%20of%20the%20Machines%5d)), that player would continue to get extra turns from Medomai's first ability. Similarly, it will also work if Medomai or a copy thereof is put onto the battlefield tapped and attacking (e.g. [Ilharg, the Raze-Boar](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bIlharg%2c%20the%20Raze-Boar%5d)).

Comment: Thanks that explanation was clear and complete. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

It totally does. Medomai doesn't care how those extra turns were created, or even whose extra turns they are. That loop doesn't work.

Source: The ability says "~ can't attack during extra turns." They were attacking with it on extra turns.

Comment: But since Mirage Mirror becomes a new instance of Medomai every turn, it will ignore that second line of the creature? I think it will apply if Medomai is still on the battlefield after being cast...

Comment: @JorgeArturoAdolioCascante no it wouldn't.  All that matters is that you are currently in an extra turn and the Mirage Mirror is currently a copy of Medomai.  You are not allowed to attack with Medomai on extra turns, even if it just came onto the battlefield or didn't start the turn as a Medomai.

Comment: @JorgeArturoAdolioCascante Why wouldn't it apply? It doesn't say "~ can't attack on extra turns granted by ~" it just says "~can't attack on extra turns" They are still extra turns even if they were created with a different Medomai, or by say a Lighthouse Chronologist, Medomai still can't attack.

Answer (score 3):

"Medomai the Ageless can’t attack during extra turns." All that Medomai cares about is "Is this an extra turn" it doesn't care what created that extra turn, so it can't attack on an extra turn it created, a different Medomai created, or one that was created by say [Nexus of Fate](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bNexus%20of%20Fate%5d). If it had been written "Medomai the Ageless can’t attack during extra turns created by Medomai the Ageless." it would be self referential and only care about the extra turns that copy of Medomai gave, and this combo would work.

Saying a creature can't attack means you can't declare it as an attacker as normal, however it can be put in tapped and attacking legally. In this way Medomai combos well with [Ilharg, the Raze-Boar](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bIlharg%2c%20the%20Raze-Boar%5d) or [Yore-Tiller Nephilim](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bYore-Tiller%20Nephilim%5d) (with a way to get it back in the graveyard). It also can create more than one extra turn, if it were given double strike or extra combat steps (I have one in my [Rafiq of the Many](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bRafiq%20of%20the%20Many%5d) EDH deck along with [Finest Hour](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bFinest%20Hour%5d) to give me 4 extra turns) since it can attack on other combat steps and gives turns every time it hits an opponent.